# how to use unique value to stop data from replicating?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have this excel document and I import the sheet from that file into my database after that I use this code to put them in separate tables:

```
insert into LP_Pending_Info(Service_order,Company,Country , HQ_AgingBase_Date ,PENDING_DAYS, Posting_Date,Service_Type,Service_TypeText,SUB_SVC_Type,Status,Status_Text,Reason,Reason_Text,Reason_Aging,SVC_Comment,ASC_Code,ASC_Name,ASC_JobNo,Model,CIC_Product,SerialNo,IN_OUT_WTY,IMEI,Defect_DESC,Detail_Type,Detail_TypeText,Repair_RCV_DT,Repair_RCV_TM,Complete_DT,SVC_Level,Consumer,Consumer_Text,TelNumber,City1,Street,Engineer_Code)
select Service_order,Company,Country , [HQ aging base date] ,PENDING_DAYS, Posting_Date,Service_Type,SERVICE_TYPE_TXT,SUB_SVC_Type,Status,Status_Text,Reason,Reason_Text,Reason_Aging,SVC_Comment,[ASC code],[ASC 

name],ASC_JOB_NO,Model,CIC_PRD,SERIAL_NO,INOUTWTY,IMEI,Defect_DESC,Detail_Type,DETAIL_TYPE_TEXT,Repair_RCV_DT,Repair_RCV_TM,Complete_DT,SVC_Level,Consumer,consumer_txt,TEL_NUMBER,City1,Street,[Engineer code]
    from LP_Pending_Jobs;

insert into LP_Part_Codes(Service_order, PartCode,serPluspart)
select Service_order, Part_code , CONVERT(nvarchar(150), Service_order)+Part_code
from LP_Pending_Jobs
cross apply (
    --unpivot
    select Part_code1 as Part_code where len(Part_code1) > 0
    union all
    select Part_code2 where len(Part_code2) > 0
    union all
    select Part_code3 where len(Part_code3) > 0
    union all
    select Part_code4 where len(Part_code4) > 0
    union all
    select Part_code5 where len(Part_code5) > 0

) unp;

insert into LP_PS_Codes(Service_Order, PS)
select Service_order,PS
from LP_Pending_Jobs
cross apply (
    select PS1 as PS where len(PS1)>0
    union all
    select PS2 where len(PS2) > 0
    union all
    select PS3 where len(PS3) > 0
    union all
    select PS4 where len(PS4) > 0
    union all
    select PS5 where len(PS5) > 0
) unp;


insert into LP_Confirmation_Codes(Service_Order, SO_NO)
select Service_order,SO
from LP_Pending_Jobs
cross apply (
    select confirmation_No1 as SO where len(confirmation_No1)>0
    union all
    select SO_NO2 where len(SO_NO2) > 0
    union all
    select SO_NO3 where len(SO_NO3) > 0
    union all
    select SO_NO4 where len(SO_NO4) > 0
    union all
    select SO_NO5 where len(SO_NO5) > 0
) unp;

----------------
insert into LP_QTY(Service_Order, QTY)
select Service_order,QTY
from LP_Pending_Jobs
cross apply (
    select QTY1 as QTY where len(QTY1)>0
    union all
    select QTY2 where len(QTY2) > 0
    union all
    select QTY3 where len(QTY3) > 0
    union all
    select QTY4 where len(QTY4) > 0
    union all
    select QTY5 where len(QTY5) > 0
) unp;


insert into LP_ASC_PO_Codes(Service_Order, ASC_PO_NO)
select Service_order,ASC_PO
from LP_Pending_Jobs
cross apply (
    select ASC_PO_No1 as ASC_PO where len(ASC_PO_No1)>0
    union all
    select ASC_PO_No2 where len(ASC_PO_No2) > 0
    union all
    select ASC_PO_No3 where len(ASC_PO_No3) > 0
    union all
    select ASC_PO_No4 where len(ASC_PO_No4) > 0
    union all
    select ASC_PO_No5 where len(ASC_PO_No5) > 0
) unp;


insert into LP_PO_Date(Service_Order, PO_Date)
select Service_order,PO_Date
from LP_Pending_Jobs
cross apply (
    select PO_DATE1 as PO_Date where len(PO_DATE1)>0
    union all
    select PO_DATE2 where len(PO_DATE2) > 0
    union all
    select PO_DATE3 where len(PO_DATE3) > 0
    union all
    select PO_DATE4 where len(PO_DATE4) > 0
    union all
    select PO_DATE5 where len(PO_DATE5) > 0
) unp;


insert into LP_SO_Date(Service_Order, SO_Date)
select Service_order,SO_Date
from LP_Pending_Jobs
cross apply (
    select SO_DATE1 as SO_Date where len(SO_DATE1)>0
    union all
    select SO_DATE2 where len(SO_DATE2) > 0
    union all
    select SO_DATE3 where len(SO_DATE3) > 0
    union all
    select SO_DATE4 where len(SO_DATE4) > 0
    union all
    select SO_DATE5 where len(SO_DATE5) > 0
) unp;
```

and because the data's are in one row I used cross apply to put each data in separate column.
The problem start when I join them , cause they show way more data that it should be.
here is the select code:

```
select distinct LP_Pending_Info.Service_Order,LP_Pending_Info.Pending_Days,
LP_Pending_Info.Service_Type,LP_Pending_Info.ASC_Code,LP_Pending_Info.Model,
LP_Pending_Info.IN_OUT_WTY, LP_Part_Codes.PartCode,LP_PS_Codes.PS,
LP_Confirmation_Codes.SO_NO,LP_Pending_Info.Engineer_Code,serPluspart
from LP_Pending_Info
inner join LP_Part_Codes on LP_Pending_Info.Service_order = LP_Part_Codes.Service_order
inner join LP_PS_Codes on LP_Part_Codes.Service_Order = LP_PS_Codes.Service_Order
inner join LP_Confirmation_Codes on LP_PS_Codes.Service_Order = LP_Confirmation_Codes.Service_Order
order by LP_Pending_Info.Service_order;
```

I asked around and I come to this point that I need a unique column, so I added

> 'serPluspart'

this column to my table in hope that it'll fix my problem but when I use my select I still see the extra data.
here is the first 25 record:
[image]

for every service order at top I have five part code, by looking at the picture the part code `'4182134076'` should have 2 rows because it has two part code but it shows that service order for 8 times and I don't know how to fix it. appreciate any suggestion.
the excel input file for this `'4182134076'` service order:

```
   Service_order    PENDING_DAYS    SERVICE_TYPE    ASC code    MODEL   INOUTWTY    Part_code1  PS1 ASC_PO_No1  confirmation_No1    QTY1    PO_DATE1    SO_DATE1    Part_code2  PS2 ASC_PO_No2  SO_NO2  QTY2    PO_DATE2    SO_DATE2    Part_code3  PS3 ASC_PO_No3  SO_NO3  QTY3    PO_DATE3    SO_DATE3    Part_code4  PS4 ASC_PO_No4  SO_NO4  QTY4    PO_DATE4    SO_DATE4    Part_code5  PS5 ASC_PO_No5  SO_NO5  QTY5    PO_DATE5    SO_DATE5    Engineer code

4182134076                36             CI        4285818  SM-A310FZDDTHR  LP      GH96-09938A P   4182134076/1    1000237676          1   09.07.2016              GH81-13601A U   4182134076  1000224921  1   05.06.2016                                                                                                                                                                                                                             7086002211
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the output, you would expect eight rows because you have three pairs of binary alternatives (PartCode - GH81-13601A or GH96-09938A; PS - P or U; SO_NO 1000224921 OR 1000237676).  Because PartCode, PS, and SO_NO come from three different tables and the only inner join is on the service_order, you will get 2^3 rows. Without seeing the data, it is hard to say exactly what is wrong, but I assume when you say you are only expecting two rows, that these three elements are linked, although the tables are not.  I suspect you need some foreign keys, but without some sample data, I cannot be sure.

OK having seen the input data I know what to do!  In LP_Part_Codes get rid of your column serPluspart (it is not helping).  Now add a SubOrder (smallint) to each of LP_Part_Codes, LP_PS_Codes and LP_Confirmation_Codes.

Next add a column to your unpivots e.g:

```
insert into LP_PS_Codes(Service_Order, PS, SubOrder)
select Service_order,PS,SubOrder
from LP_Pending_Jobs
cross apply (
select PS1 as PS, 1 AS SubOrder where len(PS1)>0
union all
select PS2, 2 AS SubOrder where len(PS2) > 0
union all
select PS3, 3 AS SubOrder where len(PS3) > 0
union all
select PS4, 4 AS SubOrder where len(PS4) > 0
union all
select PS5, 5 AS SubOrder where len(PS5) > 0
) unp;
```

Do the same for LP_Part_Codes and LP_Confirmation_Codes.

Now you can amend your main select by adding LP_Part_Codes.SubOrder = LP_PS_Codes.SubOrder = LP_Confirmation_Codes.SubOrder

And you will now have only two records for this order.

HTH

Jonathan

Comment: I used the relationship to connect the tables with service order as primary key. how do you want the sample data?

Comment: If you could just post the input data (ie the excel sheet data) for service order 4182134076, that should be enough.  As I wrote though, three separate tables all linked just with the same service order, which I suspect is not unique in the excel sheet, will give multiple results.  I strongly suspect you need to be unique on service_order and service_sub_order.

Comment: I added the excel part for that service order in the end of the question.

Comment: Ok understood - I see what the problem is. Give me a couple of minutes and I'll edit my answer

Comment: just one question. one of my column 'SO_NO' have empty values as well(null). what should I do about them? cause in output it won't show them!

Comment: Then left join the table in question (LP_Confirmation_Codes, I  presume), instead of inner join, and use ISNULL(SO_NO, '').